# Use regex to remove/exclude columns from dataframe - Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which can be generated from the code below

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :[1,2,3],'date1': ['12/31/2007','11/25/2009','10/06/2005'],'date1derived':[0,0,0],'val1':[2,4,6],'date2': ['12/31/2017','11/25/2019','10/06/2015'],'date2derived':[0,0,0],'val2':[1,3,5],'date3':['12/31/2027','11/25/2029','10/06/2025'],'date3derived':[0,0,0],'val3':[7,9,11]})
```

The dataframe looks like as shown below

[image]

I would like to remove columns that contain "derived" in their name. I tried different regex but couldn't get the expected output.

```
    df = df.filter(regex='[^H\dDerived]+', axis=1)
    df = df.filter(regex='[^Derived]',axis=1)
```

Can you let me know the right regex to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`pd.Index.difference()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) with [`df.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

```
df[df.columns.difference(df.filter(like='derived').columns,sort=False)]
```

---

```
   person_id       date1  val1       date2  val2       date3  val3
0          1  12/31/2007     2  12/31/2017     1  12/31/2027     7
1          2  11/25/2009     4  11/25/2019     3  11/25/2029     9
2          3  10/06/2005     6  10/06/2015     5  10/06/2025    11
```

Comment: @AVLES `df.filter(like='derived').columns` gives you columns having `derived` , using `pd.Index.difference()`, we find the difference between `df.columns` and the filtered columns. `sort=False` to keep the original order. :)

Comment: Okay, usually when we do drop, the order of columns can change?

Comment: @AVLES no, it wouldn't, you can opt to `drop()` too. However, any algorithm which returns a copy of list would be faster , you will anyway slice the df.(IMO)

Comment: @AVLES i think you are looking for .`dropna(axis=1)` in this case

Answer (score 2):

You can use a zero-width negative lookahead to make sure the string `derived` does not come anywhere:

```
^(?!.*?derived)
```

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `(?!.*?derived)` is the negative lookahead pattern that makes sure `derived` does not come in the string

Your pattern `[^Derived]` will match any single character that are not one of D/e/r/i/v/e/d .

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want to drop columns has `derived` in it. This should do:

```
df.drop(df.filter(like='derived').columns, 1)

Out[455]:
   person_id       date1  val1       date2  val2       date3  val3
0          1  12/31/2007     2  12/31/2017     1  12/31/2027     7
1          2  11/25/2009     4  11/25/2019     3  11/25/2029     9
2          3  10/06/2005     6  10/06/2015     5  10/06/2025    11
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. It will drop all columns that only contain "derived" and it will not drop columns that contain "der". Am I right?

Comment: yes. It must has full word `derived` in its name to drop.

Answer (score 1):

```
df[[c for c in df.columns if 'derived' not in c ]]
```

**Output**

```
   person_id       date1  val1       date2  val2       date3  val3
0          1  12/31/2007     2  12/31/2017     1  12/31/2027     7
1          2  11/25/2009     4  11/25/2019     3  11/25/2029     9
2          3  10/06/2005     6  10/06/2015     5  10/06/2025    11
```

Comment: A quick question. Let's say in my dataframe "date2" column was empty, how do I remove the column? I mean when values are NA, we usually drop rows(record), but if date2 column is all NA, I would like to drop "date2" column. Can you let me know how to do this?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html will help, use how='all' with column name

Comment: I mean I would like to drop columns only if all values in them are "NA". iT SHOULD NOT drop columns for 1 0r 2 NA's

Comment: Yes how="all" is there for that purpose...go through the doc u will get it

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of pandas, you can use string methods on the index and columns. Here, [str.endswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html#pandas.Series.str.endswith) seems like a good fit.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :[1,2,3],'date1': ['12/31/2007','11/25/2009','10/06/2005'],
                   'date1derived':[0,0,0],'val1':[2,4,6],'date2': ['12/31/2017','11/25/2019','10/06/2015'],
                   'date2derived':[0,0,0],'val2':[1,3,5],'date3':['12/31/2027','11/25/2029','10/06/2025'],
                   'date3derived':[0,0,0],'val3':[7,9,11]})

df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.endswith('derived')]

print(df)
```

O/P:

```
   person_id       date1  val1       date2  val2       date3  val3
0          1  12/31/2007     2  12/31/2017     1  12/31/2027     7
1          2  11/25/2009     4  11/25/2019     3  11/25/2029     9
2          3  10/06/2005     6  10/06/2015     5  10/06/2025    11
```